# Any reference for Angular material 2 responsive?

Tags: angular, angular-material, responsive

I am new to Angular Material 2. How can I achieve responsive theaming?

Comment: There are multiple theming frameworks that can achieve this. Try Bootstrap or Materialize.

Comment: Can you provide any reference link for Materialize. I am planning to use Angular Material (https://material.angular.io/).

Comment: [Here you are](https://www.google.com/search?q=materialize)

Comment: http://materializecss.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of frameworks that you can use. You can use Bootstrap, Material and Zurb Foundation which are very stable:

For Material:
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk

Also you can get help from here: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

For Bootstrap 3:
npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 --save

For Bootstrap 4:
npm install bootstrap --save

If you added the Bootstrap CSS file locally, just import it in .angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.scss"
],
If Bootstrap 4 then:
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.scss"
],
```

You can refer to these links:
https://codingthesmartway.com/using-bootstrap-with-angular/

For Zurb Foundation, you can refer to this blog:
https://shermandigital.com/blog/zurb-foundation-with-angular-cli/